# Mathematical description of the wave function $\psi$ as a standing wave

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction

What is the mathematical description of the travelling waves that, when combined, yield the Schrödinger standing wave in the illustration below?

[image: Schrödinger standing wave]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a homework-type problem, I'm not going to work it out for you. What you need is to write down the product of two functions to get each of the traveling waves. These two functions are, a) an envelop function that remains stationary (looks like a Gaussian), and b) a wave that is propagating in a particular direction. The latter would be a sine or cosine function that is shifted as a function of time [as in $f(x-tv)$]. The two different traveling waves will then differ simply in terms of the direction of the shift.